# Split an "array"-like string

Tags: java, arrays, split, processing

I want to extract some data from an "array"-like string (from a file), which is this:

```
PR=[[20,5],[24,11],[24,13]]
```

Also, I want to store the data into an actual array, I mean:

```
int[][] pr = {{20,5},{24,11},{24,13}};
```

EDIT: Can I use Regex or something like that?

Comment: Thats not a question, and you didnt provided any research effort so you "question" is going to be CLOSED soon

Comment: I was trying to use the `split()` method.

Comment: Regex is a bad idea.
`data.split("=");`
data[1] is the array itself. Write your own, simple parser

Comment: @Toumash: I added the question after posting it.

Comment: Also, I parsed everything after the "PR=".

Comment: What do you mean, by "parsed"? Will your data always be twodimensional, or more?

Comment: Yes, you can use a regular expression. If you know for certain that the "array-like string" always represents a two-dimensional array, the inability of regular expressions to parse arbitrarily nested braces does not apply.

Comment: I extracted everething afther the variable name and the equal symbol.

Comment: You could do `((?:\[)\d+,\d+(?:\]))+` or better `((?:\[)(\d+,?)+(?:\]))+` and split by `,`

Comment: Why i can't answer the question? Here is my solution: http://pastie.org/10263585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are many JSON libraries that you can use, pay attention that you need to create a corresponding class and object in order to deserialize teh JSON string.

The following demonstrates how to do it with Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Matrix implements Serializable {
    Integer[][] matrix;
    Matrix(){};

    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Matrix matrix = gson.fromJson("{\"matrix\" : [[20,5],[24,11],[24,13]]}", Matrix.class);
        System.out.println("matrix = \n" + matrix);

    }

    public String toString() {
        String res = "";
        if (matrix == null)
            return res;

        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++) {
                res += matrix[i][j] + ",";
            }
            res += "\n";
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
matrix = 
20,5,
24,11,
24,13,
```